# Async pg-node query execution on object's array

Tags: postgresql, asynchronous, underscore.js, node-postgres

I have an object's array which I need to iterate through, and insert each item into the DB (postgres). I'm using `_.each` in order to iterate through the array.

```
arr = [ 
      {name: 'Aaron',    description: 'First'},
      {name: 'Brian',    description: 'Second'},
      {name: 'Chris',    description: 'Third'}
]

    var i = 0;
    _.each(array, function(lt){     
        var client = new pg.Client(self.getConnString());
        client.connect(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                          //doSomething//
            }
            var sql = 'insert into load_test (name,description) values(\''+lt.name+'\', \''+lt.description+'\')';
            console.log(i + " <- query: " + lt.name + " desc: " + lt.description);
            query = client.query(sql);
            query.on('end', client.end.bind(client));
            i++;
        });
    });//each
```

How can I write this function (`_each`) in the way that it will be async for each query execution?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to? What possible benefit would there be?

Comment: I would be able to execute "insert" query for several times synchronously

Comment: Yes, but why? Why use multiple connections for multiple inserts? Do you think it will be faster or something?

Comment: Oh, now I got your question :)... I've tried to take the client creation out of the each scope, but then I'm getting memory leak exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution looks like this :

```
self.InsertLT = function(index, callback){
        var client = new pg.Client(self.getConnString());
        if (index < arr.length){
            //console.log('index = ' + index);
            var sql = 'insert into table (name,description) values(\''+arr[index].name+'\', \''+arr[index].description+'\')';
            //console.log(sql);
            client.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) { 
                    logger.error(self.ERR_CONNECT_TO_DB + ' --> ' + err);
                    callback(-1);    
                }   
                client.query(sql, function(err, result){    
                    if (err){    
                        logger.error(self.ERR_RUNNING_QUERY + ' --> ' + err);    
                        callback(-1);    
                    }    
                    else{
                        client.end();
                        self.InsertLT(++index,callback);
                    }
                });//query
            });
        }
        else{
            callback();
        }
```

Comment: You are creating a new connection for every insert statement. That is insane.

Comment: Yes, but you are having to set up and close down a connection *for every insert*

Comment: So ? stateless connection to DB... I can also implement it by using a connection pool, and then I would need to get a Done in connection callback, and then just to use it instead calling client.end()

Answer (score -2):

OK. I think I understand where you're coming from now.

You want to make three changes I'd say.

1. Create the connection ("client") outside the loop
2. Use parameterised queries
3. Wrap the inserts in a transaction (so they all work or all fail together)

I don't do node, but reworking your code it would look something like:

```
arr = [ 
      {name: 'Aaron',    description: 'First'},
      {name: 'Brian',    description: 'Second'},
      {name: 'Chris',    description: 'Third'}
];

var i = 0;
var client = new pg.Client(self.getConnString());
client.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        //doSomething//
    }
    // I don't know how node does parameterised queries, but it will look
    // something like this
    var sql   = 'insert into load_test (name,description) values(?,?)';
    var query = client.query(sql);
    _.each(arr, function(lt) {
        console.log(i + " <- query: " + lt.name + " desc: " + lt.description);
        // There might be separate bind + excecute calls
        query.execute(lt.name, lt.description);
        i++;
    });
// There might be a client.disconnect() needed here
```

You'll need to consult the documentation for the proper syntax.

Typically you'd connect at application startup and keep the database connection around until it quits. I'm guessing you've got references to the database connection still referenced in a closure somewhere. If your queries need a "completed()" or "discard()" method or similar, make sure you call that to release resources too.

Comment: First thanks for the answer ! In pg-node, client query is the query execution